# Value not showing when sub folder is coming

Tags: php

This is my table

```
tag  enabled

bank   1
WT     1
Credit 1
Debit  1
EMI    1
```

My query is:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM payment WHERE enabled = '1'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $gateway='';
        if($data['tag']=='credit') {
            $gateway='/'.getPaymentGateway($data['gateway'],'tag');
        }

        include('payment/'.$data['tag'].$gateway.'/display.php');   

        ...
    }
```

The problem is, it shows until credit, not showing debit and EMI.
That's because, the credit has sub folder.

The function `getPaymentGateway` is:

```
function getPaymentGateway($id,$field) {      
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM    payment_gateway  WHERE id = '".$id."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    return   $data[$field];

}
```

Comment: $data['tag']=='credit' shouldn't be $data['tag']=='Credit'?

Comment: credit only. I gave exact value

Comment: if I wirte SELECT * FROM    payment_gateway  WHERE id = '".$id."' and tag"='credit', it shows below value

Comment: The column `gateway` doesn't exists in the `payment` table. Am I correct?

Comment: @Tomás Yes. If credit come as first again values are not shown

Comment: If `gateway` does not exist in the `payment` table, then WHY you are doing `$data['gateway']` inside the `while`??

Comment: I have to put any file exist or something?

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to do assoc, you are not joining any tables keep it simple.

```
 if(!$result){
      // error with query 
      return mysql_error();
    }else{
      while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $gateway='';
        if($data['tag']=='credit') $gateway='/'.getPaymentGateway($data['gateway'],'tag');
        include('payment/'.$data['tag'].$gateway.'/display.php');   
     }
    }
```

Comment: This does not solve OP problem. AND `mysql_fetch_array` is worst than `mysql_fetch_assoc` as it uses more memory. http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-fetch-array.php